# Returning a json object without square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which returns an object of form:
`[{"key":"name","value":"ali","key":"age","value":"56"}]` when called as given below. How can I have it return same kind of object but without the square brackets?

```
setProperties('{"name":"ali","age":"56"}');

function setProperties(str) {
    var properties = [];
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
    for (property in json) {
      properties.push({
        key: property,
        value: json[property]});
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return properties[0]; // returns the first element of the list instead of the whole list
```

Comment: My goodness. Can't believe I asked this question. So the function was returning an array and I just had to return first element of the array or not use array at all in the function. :-/

Answer (score 5):

The square brackets indicate an Array literal, so if you just select the first element of the Array: `[{"name":"ali","age":"56","height":"xyz"}][0]` it returns the Object you want.